# Get web part TypeName using CSOM

Tags: web-part, client-object-model

Can we retrieve the TypeName of a web part using CSOM?

Comment: What would be the reason I get Access denied during the web service call? I have the highest permissions possible in the environment. If it makes a difference, I'm calling this from an auto-hosted SharePoint 2013 App.

Comment: I personally used server-side CSOM instead of Vadim's code so haven't checked the code. However, you could try to call other services. I think there should not be any specific permissions needed for this service in particular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't seem possible to retrieve all the web part properties (like `TypeName`) via CSOM

But it could be performed via `WebPartPagesWebService` SharePoint Web Service as demonstrated below:

```
function getWebPartProperties(pageUrl,completeFn,errorFn)
{
    var soapEnv =
        '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">  \
            <soap:Body>  \
                <GetWebPartProperties2 xmlns="http://microsoft.com/sharepoint/webpartpages">  \
                    <pageUrl>' + pageUrl + '</pageUrl>   \
                    <storage>Shared</storage>   \
                    <behavior>Version3</behavior>   \
                </GetWebPartProperties2>  \
            </soap:Body>   \
        </soap:Envelope>';

    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_vti_bin/WebPartPages.asmx",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapEnv,
        complete: completeFn,
        error: errorFn,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
    });
}                


$(function() {
    getWebPartProperties('/SitePages/DevHome.aspx',
        function(xhr,textStatus){
            $(xhr.responseXML).find("WebPart").each(function() {
                var wpTypeName = $(this).find('type').attr('name'); //get Web Part TypeName
                console.log(wpTypeName);
            });

        },
        function(xhr,textStatus,errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown);
        });
});
```

Comment: Btw does this or something like this work for publishing pages?

Comment: I had a chance to verify it for publishing pages and it works for me

Comment: oh, apparently the error was not due to publishing pages but web part types. Tasks web part returns only one property "Cannot import this Web Part" apparently..