# Check if webpart is of type XsltListViewWebPart

Tags: web-part, jsom

How can I check if a webpart is of type XsltListViewWebPart in Sharepoint 2013 using JSOM

I'm trying to return a list XsltListViewWebParts on a page this is as far as I have gone

```
function get_webpart_info(callback) {            
        var pageFile = context.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(_spPageContextInfo.serverRequestPath);
        var webPartManager = pageFile.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
        var webPartDefs = webPartManager.get_webParts();
        context.load(webPartDefs, 'Include(WebPart)');
        context.executeQueryAsync(
            function () {
                console.log('Number of webparts ' + webPartDefs.get_count());
                var wp_xslts = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < webPartDefs.get_count() ; i++) {
                    var webPartDef = webPartDefs.getItemAtIndex(i);
                    var webpart = webPartDef.get_webPart();
                    //I'm stuck here coz I don't know how to check  the type of webpart


                }
                return callback(wp_xslts);
            }, function onError(sender, args) {
                console.log(args.get_message());
                return callback(null);
            }
        );
    }
```

Comment: what code have you tried?

Comment: I don't think this is possible via client script... i think i tried something like this via powershell once.

Comment: This might be useful to you: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/86157/get-web-part-typename-using-csom. Once you get the typename, you can check if it is XsltListViewWebPart.

Comment: @Akhoy this also works. The authenticated user calling this method should have the necessary permissions to import webparts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't explicitly check the type of the web part, but what you can do is load the properties and see if ListName is set. That should be enough to tell you if it's an XSLTListViewPart, and if you hit a conflict there are a bunch of other properties that might help you qualify it. Here's an example:

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext();
var pageFile = ctx.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(pageUrlGoesHere);
var webPartManager = pageFile.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
var webPartDefs = webPartManager.get_webParts();
ctx.load(webPartDefs,'Include(WebPart)');
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
  function () {
    for(var i = 0;i < webPartDefs.get_count();i++) {
       var webPartDef = webPartDefs.getItemAtIndex(i);
       var webPart = webPartDef.get_webPart();
ctx.load(webPart,'Properties');
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
  function () {
    var properties = webPart.get_properties();
    console.log(properties.get_fieldValues());
   var fieldValues = properties.get_fieldValues();
   if (fieldValues.ListName)
   {
        //Add to list, etc. May want to check more properties or change conditional.
   }
  },
  function(sender,args){
     console.log(args.get_message());
  });
    }
  },
  function(sender,args){
     console.log(args.get_message());
  });
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works for authenticated users with permissions to import webparts on the page. Otherwise no properties are available.

Comment: Hmm, good to know! For an approach that works with non-authenticated users, you could potentially check the Title URL of the web part - this is defined for list views but rarely for other types of webparts. Unfortunately, it may not be an exact listing.

Comment: does this work in Add-in ?

Comment: What type of add-in, and what are you trying to get information about? SharePoint add-ins are typically not able to access any information about the page that contains them, so you wouldn't be able to use this to look at web parts on the same page as the Add-In. However, this code works in a standard Script Editor web part.